# Yes/No : Any uniformly continuous function$ f : ( X,d) \rightarrow (Y,d)$ carries bounded set to bounded

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Any uniformly continuous function$ f : ( X,d) \rightarrow (Y,d)$ carries  bounded set to bounded set . True/false

My attempt  : I this statement is true  take  $X= Y = \mathbb{R}$ and  $d= |x-y|$

Is its correct ?

Comment: The point is that you can't just show it's true for a very particular choice of metric space(s) and then conclude it holds for all possible metric spaces.

Comment: Hint: Try to find a counter-example in a space which does not satisfy the Heine-Borel property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X=\Bbb R$ has the discrete metric and $Y=\Bbb R$ has the usual metric, any subset of $X$ is bounded, and the identity is uniformly continuous ($\delta=1$ always works). So NO.

What **is** true is that a *totally bounded* subset is mapped to a *totally bounded* set.
That makes a great difference.

Comment: sir @Henno  why u take $ \delta  =1$   why not $\delta= 1/2$ ?

Comment: @jasmine $\frac12$ is possible too, but $d(x,y) < 1$ implies $x=y$ already.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Uniformly continuous function can be prolonged by continuity on the boundary of each open and bounded set. To prove this statement, you can prove that every uniformly continuous function are [Cauchy-continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-continuous_function)

Comment: Why do you think your hint addresses the original question (which, incidentally, has negative answer)?